# Backup ALL email accounts: Using 2016 MacBook Pro, OSX Sierra 10.12.6, Outlook for Mac v16.10

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, backup

In Outlook for Mac v16, I have an Exchange account, a Gmail account and a Hotmail account.  I want to backup ALL email.  when I do File Export in Outlook, it doesn't tell me if ALL three are backed up.  If not, how do I backup each one individually?

Answer (score 0):

When exporting, all three accounts should have been exported. If you want to backup each one individually, you can categorize all the messages in that account, then use Export to save all messages with that category.